# proper way of Implementing a listener on HTTP

Tags: c#, networking, notifications

1- Client application sends a a request to an http server (ashx file, IHttpHandler).
Remark-1: Client is a .dll which will be hosted by other stand alone applications.
Remark-2: Server was first developed as a web service, then for unknown reasons it became very slow, so we implemented it from scratch.
2- Server registers the request in database so that a long duration process is performed on data.
3- Client needs to get notified when the process is finished.

First thing that crossed my mind was implementing a Timer in client. Although I'm not sure if it is ok to do it inside of a host application which is not aware of such usage.

Then it crossed my mind if there may be a something useful in TcpListener or lower layers of socket programming instead of a high frequency timer and flooding server with update requests.

So, I appreciate any suggestion on proper way of doing this task.

**UPDATE:**

After giving some order to my codes, I update requirements like this:

1- Server "Broadcast"s ID of clients, like: "Client-a, read your instructions", then "Client-c", "Clinet-j",... . This is not mission critical, if a client looses the broadcast, it will return after one minute by a timer tick and will check instructiosn.

2- This server is gona be hosted on a shared hosting plan, at least at first. Solution must be acceptable in boundary of share hosting.

3- preferably all clients connect to the only one socket. No usage of extra resources.

Any recommendation is appreciated.

Comment: the title suggests you're writing the server, but the body suggests you're writing the client; which is it? what sort of scale (number of clients/connections) are we talking about here? is it limited to http/1.1? or could http/2 be used? or maybe something in the middle, like web-sockets (which starts as http/1.1 before transitioning to a different protocol)

Comment: This sounds like a poor use case for HTTP. Maybe a message queue system would be more suitable. Or you could perhaps do something based on websockets (or some other kind of socket connection which is open for the duration of the long-running task...but it depends how long you're really talking about - seconds, minutes, hours, days??)

Comment: Marc, thanks for response. Both client and server are developed by myself. Every change is possible, and having both versions in parallel is also possible.

Comment: I'm talking about maybe 25 clients working together and duration of response anything from a few milliseconds to waiting for return of a user from a long weekend and pressing an accept button.

Comment: Adyson, thanks for response, I accept this is a poor usage of HTTP, any modification is possible, at least a parallel server address can be added for better performance. As I said once I got stuck with response time of standard web service, so I went one level down.

Comment: Use an async listener (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.httplistener.begingetcontext).  then in callback write to database and wait for data to be store before sending a response.